# Whether $||a||_{L^p} +||b||_{L^p}\le||\sqrt{a^2+b^2}||_{L^p}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, integral-inequality

$a=a(x), b=b(x)$ are elements of $L^p(\Omega)$, $\Omega$ is bounded open subset of $R^n$.

Whether $||a||_{L^p} +||b||_{L^p}\le||\sqrt{a^2+b^2}||_{L^p}$  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way.  Let $p=1$, and take constant functions $a=3$, and $b=4$.   $3+4 > 5.$